# parallel execution c#

Tags: c#-4.0, filesystems

I have following code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"mynetwork\dirall", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    list.Add(file);
}
```

Directory has some 2 million files. I want to build the index out of it that I
will write to file from the list object I populate.

It takes near about 45 mins to exectute. Can I divide this process to execute parallelly? 
Any idea? Threading or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using following code that I got from the Stackoverflow!

```
    // Takes same patterns, and executes in parallel
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDirs(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    {
        return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, searchPattern, searchOption);
    }

    // Takes same patterns, and executes in parallel
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string[] paths,string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        return paths.AsParallel().SelectMany(path => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption));
    }
```